# jquery smooth scroll to different url

Tags: jquery

I have this simple snippet working on site that allows me to use only jquery 1.3.2

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".scroll").click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top - 50}, 500);
});
});
```

The problem is that it prevents loading another url after click. If I remove event.prevent, everything is ok, but the screen flickers because browser wants to jump to  and then script fires with smooth scroll. I need to have smooth scrolling without flickering and also beeing able to go to different url. What are you suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `.scroll` class from hyperlinks that go to different pages.

Alternatively, change your selector so it only applies to hyperlinks that are hashes:

```
$('.scroll[href^="#"]').click(function(event) {
```